# How to generate the configuration and plugins from local .gql file?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I would like to generate graphql configuration using graphql-codegen. If our backend dev only provides a `.gql` file, how to I generate configuration and plugins from this local file by edit the `codegen.yml` file?

I've tried to edit my codegen file to the below, but it does not work when I command `yarn codegen`

```
overwrite: true
schema: **'localfile.gql'**
documents: ./*.{ts,tsx}
generates:
  types/generated/introspection.graphql:
    plugins:
      - schema-ast
    config:
      sort: true
  types/generated/graphql.tsx:
    config:
      # typescript
      declarationKind: 'interface'
      scalars:
        DateTime: string
        ID: string
      namingConvention:
        enumValues: change-case#upperCase
      avoidOptionals:
        field: true
      # TypeScript Operations
      skipTypename: true
      # typescript-react-apollo
      withHooks: true

    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-apollo
```

I would like know how to generate the configuration and plugins from local .gql file?

Comment: have you tried to use relative path in `schema` option? `schema: ./localfile.gql`

Comment: Yes, but it does not work... Should I revise my script in package.json? `graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml --require dotenv/config && prettier --write \"types/generated/*\" && eslint \"types/generated/*.{tx,tsx}\" --fix`